# Проблема с пакетом NuGet Asp.net.mvc 5.2.7

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nuget

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Начал изучение платформы sap.net  столкнулся с проблемой  не совместимости пакетов NuGet подскажите как исправить кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой??

Comment: судя по картинке проект asp net core . а тяните из nuget библиотеки для net framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы используете не совместимые между собой версии проекта и библиотеки. В мире .net существует 2 версии: .NET Framework (2.0, 4.0, 4.5 ... 4.8, условно старая версия) и  .NET Core (1.0 ... 3.1 и новая версия). Для них были разработыны разные версии ASP.NET и ASP.NET Core. В это у вас и ошибка. Вы создали проект .NET Core 3.1, а устанавливаете в неё старую библиотеку.

Если вы хотите использовать Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.2.7, создайте проект ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework), при создании проекта, можно указать, что вам необходимо MVC или Web Api и т.д. и студия сама поставит нужные библиотеки.

Или сразу переходите на ASP.NET Core :).